# I want to print a table without printing all the rows, is there a way to do it?

Tags: php, pdo, printing, rows

I need to print a table but I don't want an specific part to been printed on the paper
In this case the last 3 
'''

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hoja de Prestamo</td>
            <td>Cod. de Prestamo</td>
            <td>Socio</td>
            <td>Documento</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>               
        <?php
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM detalleprestamo AS det 
            LEFT JOIN hojadeprestamo AS hoj ON det.`relahojadeprestamo` = hoj.`idhojadeprestamo`
            LEFT JOIN ejemplar AS eje ON eje.`idejemplar` = det.`relaejemplar`
            LEFT JOIN libro AS lib ON lib.`idlibro` = eje.`relalibro`
            LEFT JOIN persona AS per ON per.`relasocio` = hoj.relasocio;");                     
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                       
            foreach ($results as $row){
                echo "<tr>".
                    "<td>".$row['idhojadeprestamo']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['iddetalleprestamo']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['apellido'] . ", " . $row['nombres']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['dni']."</td>".
                    "<td>".
                        "<a id='th' title='Modificar' href = '../prestamos/modificarprestamo.php?iddetalleprestamo=".$row['iddetalleprestamo']."'>".
                            "<img src='../imagenes/actualizar.png' >".
                        "</a>".
                    "</td>".
                    "<td>".
                        "<a id='th' title='Registrar' href = '../prestamos/registrarprestamo1.php?iddetalleprestamo=".$row['iddetalleprestamo']."'>".
                            "<img src='../imagenes/registrar.png' >".
                        "</a>".
                    "</td>".
                    "<td>".
                        "<a id='th' title='Agregar prestamo' href ='../detalleprestamos/agregardetalleprestamo1.php?iddetalleprestamo=".$row['iddetalleprestamo']."'>".
                            "<img src='../imagenes/agregar.png' >".
                        "</a>".
                    "</td>".
                "</tr>";
            } 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            }
        $db = null;             
    ?>
```

'''

I want to show the `<td>` with the Images but when I press control+P I don't want these images to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need make some additions in the CSS layer.

Use `@media print` in your CSS:

```
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Then as usual, use the class in your image tags:

```
"<img src='../imagenes/actualizar.png' class='noprint'>".
```

Comment: I don't know what happened but at first it seemed to work, but now it doesn't.
When I charge the page the icons and rows with the "noprint" class don't appear as they should, but they don't appear when I try to print which is nice